# launchd script file access blocked by sandboxd

Tags: terminal, launchd, sandbox

I've written a small shell script that downloads some server data and saves them into a [restic](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) repository. The restic repository files are on a mounted volume. The script works fine if I run it in the Terminal.

To run this script daily I created a launchd `.plist` file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Watching the output logs, I can see that the restic command fails to access its files.

The system logs show a sandboxd warning that blocked restic.
I've granted Full Disk Access to the restic binary, but that didn't do the trick.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in a chain of scripts, the parent caller needs to have the correct privileges, to prevent a block by sandboxd. So, I've simply added the following programs for full-disk access:

- bash
- zsh
- restic
- launchd
- Terminal

I am pretty confident that you could shrink the list to more safe default, but for my use case I prefer to leave it like that

As well important: I've changed the shebang of my scripts from `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to simply `#!/bin/bash`

That did the trick for me and finally everything works as intended